# how to hide title in Eclipse Title bar?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I don't want to show title in eclipse title bar. Please provide me the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you want, this might not be possible.

For the Eclipse IDE and all the Eclipse editions you can find on the Eclipse.org download site, this is *not* possible.

For you own RCP based application, this is easy, as you just need to set the title in the `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor`